API_KEY_ANDROID_APP_BLOCKED - Routes API
I'm having problems with the Routes API. The ApiKey is restricted so that only my application can use it. I'm using retrofit to make a request but I'm getting a 403 error all the time.
I've tried passing the packagename and signature key as a header and it still won't let me. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
enter image description here

I already have a solution. The problem was in how to pass the SHA-1 key. Characters ‘:’ must be removed from the key
This is my interceptor for the request:
class RoutesInterceptor @Inject constructor() : Interceptor {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
    val request = chain.request()

    val newRequest = request.newBuilder()
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("X-Goog-Api-Key", BuildConfig.googleApiKey)
        .addHeader("X-Goog-FieldMask", "*")
        .addHeader("X-Android-Package", "YOUR PACKAGE NAME")
        .addHeader("X-Android-Cert", "13AC624158AD920199CAB14582")
        .build()

    return chain.proceed(newRequest)
}
}

